# Ruby class name is in symbol list but is not recognized by the interpreter

Tags: ruby, interpreter, symbols

I'm learning about symbols and I was surprised to discover that all symbols in a file are included in the `Symbol.all_symbols` array when I dump it as the very first line of my file.
But if I try to access a class that is defined further down I get `NameError`, in other words it is an unrecognized symbol.

```
puts "DefinedAtEnd is in symbol list: \
 #{Symbol.all_symbols.select {|s| s =~ /^DefinedAtEnd/} != nil} "
puts "do_it is in symbol list: \
 #{Symbol.all_symbols.select {|s| s =~ /^do_it/} != nil} "
puts "foo is in symbol list: #{Symbol.all_symbols.select {|s| s =~ /^foo/} != nil} "

#d = DefinedAtEnd.new    # This will get a NameError

class DefinedAtEnd
  def do_it
    foo = 'bar'
    puts 'In method do_it'
  end
end
```

Running the above gets this result:

```
DefinedAtEnd is in symbol list: true 
do_it is in symbol list: true 
foo is in symbol list: true
```

But if I uncomment the line `d = DefinedAtEnd.new` then I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant DefinedAtEnd (NameError)
```

It seems that the parser (metparser?) is parsing through the entire file once before starting to 'execute' lines of code yet it has not built out the classes. Perhaps it's some kind of 'pre-pass' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between parsing a source file and executing its code. It happens in two stages. During parsing, the names of objects (including class names and all variables which might theoretically be assigned) are interned to the symbol table. That said, this is an implementation detail which you probably shouldn't rely on (even more so because you can't really make anything useful with it).

Generally, symbols are interned strings, i.e strings which never be garbage collected and exists only once in the whole interpreter.

```
"foo".object_id == "foo".object_id   # => false
:foo.object_id == :foo.object_id     # => true
```

Unlike strings, symbols also can't be changed in place, they are immutable.

Comment: **Parsing** vs. **executing** (interpreting) - that's the key. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The file is interpreted line-by-line; you can't reference something *in code* that hasn't been defined yet--being read is not the same thing as being initialized.

Ruby 1.9.2 outputs the following, which might be a bit more illuminating:

```
foo2.rb:7:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Object::DefinedAtEnd (NameError)
```

Comment: Yes, I'm understanding a little bit more now. I've added testing with the `defined?` operator and as you point out, the forward reference to the class is not yet defined as far as the interpreter is concerned. But the symbol **is** in the symbols table. So that does imply that the interpreter is doing a sort of first pass **read** of the file and building the symbol table.